# Data Type Error - Merging columns in a new view using SELECT AS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a [TABLE] with 3 columns like this:

[Column1-smallint] [Column2-nvarchar] [Column3-nvarchar]

I would like to create a new view with only 1 column like this:

[Column1 & Column2 & Column3]

If I try:

```
SELECT [Column1 & Column2 & Column3] AS [NewColumnName] FROM dbo.table
```

It complains about *Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar data type smallint*

How do I force convert everything to NVARCHAR in the new view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is sufficient enough for your needs:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(nvarchar, Column1) + CONVERT(nvarchar, Column2) + CONVERT(nvarchar, Column3)) AS[NewColumnName] FROM dbo.Table
```